# Android: Where close cursor using CustomAdaters in AsynTask

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a big problem.. This is the code:

```
private class ViewDataTableTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    ...

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Cursor listCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ..." , null);
        ListView table_body = new ListView(context);

        try{
            table_body.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context , listCursor));
        }finally{
             if(listCursor != null){
             listCursor.close();
        }
        ...
   }
   ...
}
```

MyAdapter is a custom `CursorAdapter` that uses the `getView()` and `newView()` method

If i run the previous code i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open 
an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery
```

It seems that  `getView()` and `newView()` method run on UI Thread!!!!!!

The question is simple: where have i to put `cursor.close()`?
I don't want to use CursorLoader and/or startManagingCursor(..)

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The got `Cursor` instance will be used by `CursorAdapter` for as long as user uses your listView. That's why you should not close the cursor so early. Whenever your instance of Activity is about to be destroyed it is time to close that cursor. Or whenever you change the cursor (if this is a case for your app) for that `CursorAdapter`, close the previously used.

And as others say reset the cursor to `CursorAdapter` on the UI thread (in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to put in an asynctask? Seems to me like you are updating UI?

Also, try to limit your cursors as much as possible for the best results; open, get info, put info in new variable, close.

Answer (score 0):

Do it on `onPostExcute()`.

`doInBackground()` is a worker thread.

and `onPreXecute()` and `onPostExcute()` are runs in `UIThread.`

In your code you are using the `context` , so it may be no longer valid inside the `doInBackground()` method.

so do it on `onPostExcute()`